# What is meant by required-api: param name=”#target” in config.xml file of AGL widgets?

Tags: xml, widget, config, application-framework, automotive-grade-linux

I am trying to understand various available AGL specific options that we can give in config.xml and I am referring to the link below

https://docs.automotivelinux.org/docs/en/halibut/apis_services/reference/af-main/2.2-config.xml.html

This is the sample config.xml file

```
<feature name="urn:AGL:widget:required-api">
<param name="#target" value="main" />
<param name="gps" value="auto" />
<param name="afm-main" value="link" />
</feature>
```

what is the need for `<param name="#target" value="main" />` and what it meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why we need this

required-api: param name="#target"

OPTIONAL(not compulsory)

It declares the name of the unit(in question it is main) requiring the listed apis. Only one instance of the param “#target” is allowed. When there is not instance of this param, it behave as if the target main was specified.